# parameter is not match when call isMember

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to call isMember to get all entities which contains specified productCode,but return error about Parameter value [test] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)];

The version of spring data jpa is 2.3.9.RELEASE

```
public class Role {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", length = 64)
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "product_code")
    @Convert(converter = StringSetConverter.class)
    private Set<String> productCode;
}

public class RoleSpec {
    public static Specification<Role> isProductCodeMember(String productCode) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Expression<Collection<String>> productCodes = root.get("productCode");
            return cb.isNotMember(productCode , productCodes);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the complete Exception message that is thrown.

Comment: @PeterMmm Thanks for reminding， this is the exception message：org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [test] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [test] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)] 
  and 
 detail can see https://github.com/cestdestiny/jpa/blob/main/README.md